# timedatectl: problem with NTP returning localtime instead of UTC time

Tags: linux, systemd, embedded, ntp, timezone

On my embedded Linux, I have a problem with time zones:

I'm trying to keep the UTC time in the RTC of the device. But somehow, timedatectl keeps adjusting time to the **local** time and not the UTC time, despite the config files telling it to work with UTC time.

I'm currently working in the timezone "UTC+1", so I expect "time*.google.com" to give me a time that is 1 hour *before* our local time. But it only gives me localtime.

timedatectl status returns the following values:

```
            Local time: Mon 2022-03-07 16:00:27 UTC
        Universal time: Mon 2022-03-07 16:00:27 UTC
                RTC time: Mon 2022-03-07 16:00:27
                Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
            NTP service: active
        RTC in local TZ: no
```

timedatectl timesync-status returns the following values:

```
    Server: (null) (time4.google.com)
Poll interval: 0 (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
Packet count: 0
```

timedatectl list-timezones returns only:

```
UTC
```

If I try to turn off the ntp (with *timedatectl set-ntp false*) I can set the real UTC time in the RCT manually, it works. But as soon as I reactivate NTP, it automatically returns to localtime, (though it keeps telling me it is UTC).

Thanks in advance for your insights..

Edit for additional information:

No /etc/localtime file :

```
root@Tep2020-88:/etc/systemd# ls -l /etc/localtime
ls: /etc/localtime: No such file or directory
```

There is no ntpd daemon running:

```
Log file: Service could not be found.
```

**systemctl status systemd-timedated.service** returned:

```
* systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timedated.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:systemd-timedated.service(8)
            man:localtime(5)
            https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated

Mar 07 15:38:33 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Mar 07 15:49:40 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Mar 07 15:49:40 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Mar 07 15:50:10 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Mar 07 16:00:27 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Mar 07 16:00:27 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Mar 07 16:00:57 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Mar 07 16:08:25 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Mar 07 16:08:25 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Mar 07 16:08:55 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
```

**systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service** returned:

```
[[0;1;32m*[[0m systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: [[0;1;32mactive (running)[[0m since Mon 2022-03-07 15:44:40 UTC; 1h 39min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
Main PID: 591 (systemd-timesyn)
    Status: "Idle."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1021)
    Memory: 668.0K
    CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
            `-591 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Mar 07 15:44:40 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Mar 07 15:44:40 Tep2020-88 systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
```

Comment: I don't have a clue, but please edit your post  to include `ls -l /etc/localtime`, `systemctl status ntpd`, `systemctl status systemd-timedated.service`, & `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` so we can see where it is pointed.

Comment: Oh.. And there is no /etc/ntpd.conf and we're using busybox on our embedded system. So I guess it's the busybox version of ntp...

Comment: You're not running ntpd, it's timesyncd, and that is sntp. I think you also need to point `/etc/localtime`, to something suitable under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` if it exists. I would look at what `hwclock` gives for some switches, again if it exists. TBH people seem to have a lot of problems that can pointed at `busybox`. If `use/share/zoneinfo` does not exist, look at what is on a full unix system, and copy the required timezeone data file across.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to experiment with that and sort it out (and edit my post with the fix when I can). Thanks.